# Possible bug with EllipticPi

Tags: special-functions

I am calculating the incomplete elliptic integral of the third kind in Mathematica 11.3 using `EllipticPi`. Since my range of `phi` goes beyond `Pi/2` I tested my calculations before and realised that Mathematica evaluates `EllipticPi[3,3*Pi/4,0.6]` as `EllipticPi[3,3*Pi/4-Pi,0.6]`. However, if `phi=m*Pi/2`, where $m \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots\}$, I always obtain the correct result
`EllipticPi[3,m*Pi/2,0.6]=m*EllipticPi[3,Pi/2,0.6]`. So I would like to ask if somebody could confirm that this is a bug (which I strongly suspect) or Mathematica simply uses a different way of calculating `EllipticPi`?

Comment: `EllipticPi[]` admittedly has not a few branch cut problems, but for $n > 1$ and $0<m<1$ there is the quasiperiodicity relation `EllipticPi[n, z, m] == (-1)^Round[Mod[z + π/2, π]/π - 1/2] EllipticPi[n, Mod[z + π/2, π] - π/2, m] + 2 Round[Mod[z + π/2, π]/π - 1/2] EllipticPi[n, m]`. Exactly what "correct result(s)" did you have in mind?

Comment: I just checked the expression you wrote and although I am not hundred percent sure, I think the second Round[]-term is responsible for the problem. When I have pi/2<z<3pi/2 I get Mod[z+pi/2,pi]=z-pi/2 and then Round[Mod[z+pi/2,pi]/pi-1/2]=0. Thus the second term vanishes while it should be 2EllipticPi[n,m]. Similarly for 3pi/2<z<5pi/2 I get Mod[z+pi/2,pi]=z-3pi/2 and then Round[Mod[z+pi/2,pi]/pi-1/2]=0. Again the second term vanishes while it should be 4EllipticPi[n,m]. I just checked for some positive terms but I suspect this problem always occurs.

Comment: Just to check if I understood your examples correctly, let's consider the following specific case: `With[{n = 3, z = 3 π/2 + π/6, m = 3/5}, N[{EllipticPi[n, z, m], (-1)^Round[Mod[z + π/2, π]/π - 1/2] EllipticPi[n, Mod[z + π/2, π] - π/2, m] + 2 Round[Mod[z + π/2, π]/π - 1/2]}, 20]]`. Altho these two expressions agree, you claim that there is a missing `4 EllipticPi[n, m]` additional term. Did I get it?

Comment: With that being said, I did my own comparisons using (apologies for the self-promotion) [my own package for Carlson integrals](https://github.com/tpfto/Carlson), and using the functions in there to compute the incomplete elliptic integral of the third kind seems to support your claim.

Comment: Yes. I suggest you to evaluate both terms without the N[] term. Then Mathematica gives for the first term EllipticPi[3,5pi/3,3/5] and for the second EllipticPi[3,-pi/3,3/5]. Of course they could be the same, however, using simple mathematical formulas one can show that there is something missing. Since I am more comfortable with mathematical notations this is what I did from the beginning. Maybe this is why I found this problem in the first place.

Comment: In the meantime, I think this is worth [reporting to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).

Comment: Ok. Shall I report it or would you prefer to report it? Since you have more experience with Mathematica you might be able to describe the problem more efficiently than I would be.

Comment: It's good to have multiple confirmatory reports, so you should also send a report even if I make one too. It would be helpful if you can tack on your analytic proof that *Mathematica*'s quasiperiodicity relation is mistaken.